# a boxed equation that should appear at the top of every beamer page

Tags: formatting

I have a boxed equation:

```
\boxed{E=mc^2}
```

and I want this to appear at the top of every page in `beamer` at the same height.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this, rather than typing it every time?

Answer (score 1):

Here, using the header mechanism of `fancyhdr`.  For some reason, the header tended to push down text, so I added a corrective `\vspace` in the header.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[R]{$\boxed{E=mc^2}$\vspace{-2\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{title of the slide}
\lipsum[3]
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Second slide}
\lipsum[1]
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Last Slide}
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]